# Check for values of $x$ that are not a basis for $V$ with basis $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ with basis $B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

I have a set $Z = \{v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, v_3 + av_1\}$.

What value of $a$ makes $Z$ not a basis for $V$?

I know that $Z$ needs to be linearly independent to be a basis. But I'm lost on what to do after this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $dimV=3$ also $|Z|=3$ so $Z$ forms a basis if and only if elements of $Z$ are linearly independent

if $B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a basis then

$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0 \Rightarrow c_1=c_2=c_3$

$a_1(v_1+v_2)+a_2(v_2+v_3)+a_3(v_3+av_1)=0 \Rightarrow (a_1+aa_3)v_1+(a_1+a_2)v_2+(a_2+a_3)v_3=0$

$(a_1+aa_3)v_1+(a_1+a_2)v_2+(a_2+a_3)v_3=0 \Rightarrow (a_1+aa_3)=(a_1+a_2)=(a_2+a_3)=0 $

$(a_1+a_2)=(a_2+a_3) \Rightarrow a_1=a_3$

$a_1=a_3 \Rightarrow a_1+aa_3=(a+1)a_1=0$

$(a+1)a_1=0 \Rightarrow a_1=0$ or $a=-1$

$a_1=0 \Rightarrow a_1=a_2=a_3=0$

$a=-1 \Rightarrow -a_2=a_3=a_1$ is a solution which means they are linearly dependent

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Evaluate the determinant:

$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & a\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}\right)$.

The vectors are given by the columns of the matrix.

$\det = 1 + a$ and so $\det$ is zero (i.e., vectors are linearly dependent and so not a basis) if $a=-1$ as in the other answer.